# Set a callback function for I2C device to get data when IO event happens

Tags: c++, c, i2c

I am trying to get data from a gyro using I2C interface and I can't figure out how can I set a event handler to check for IO instead of reading the FIFO buffer in an infinite loop.

I had done a similar thing using UART.

```
struct sigaction saio;
struct termios options;

uartFilestream = open(UART_DEV, O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY | O_NDELAY);    //Open in non blocking read/write mode

saio.sa_handler = HandleIO;
saio.sa_flags = 0;
saio.sa_restorer = NULL; 
sigaction(SIGIO,&saio,NULL);

fcntl(uartFilestream, F_SETFL, FNDELAY);
fcntl(uartFilestream, F_SETOWN, getpid());
fcntl(uartFilestream, F_SETFL,  O_ASYNC );

tcgetattr(uartFilestream, &options);

options.c_cflag = B9600 | CS8 | CLOCAL | CREAD;   //<Set baud rate
options.c_iflag = IGNPAR;
options.c_oflag = 0;
options.c_lflag = 0;

tcflush(uartFilestream, TCIFLUSH);
tcsetattr(uartFilestream, TCSANOW, &options);
```

`HandleIO` is called whenever IO happens on the the serial interface. Please tell me how can I do the same with I2C.

Here is what I did with I2C but it doesn't work.

```
fd = open("/dev/i2c-1", O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY | O_NDELAY);    //Open in non blocking read/write mode

saio.sa_handler = test_func;
saio.sa_flags = 0;
saio.sa_restorer = NULL; 
sigaction(SIGIO,&saio,NULL);

fcntl(fd, F_SETFL, FNDELAY);
fcntl(fd, F_SETOWN, getpid());
fcntl(fd, F_SETFL,  O_ASYNC );

tcgetattr(fd, &options);

options.c_cflag = B9600 | CS8 | CLOCAL | CREAD;   //<Set baud rate
options.c_iflag = IGNPAR;
options.c_oflag = 0;
options.c_lflag = 0;

tcflush(fd, TCIFLUSH);
tcsetattr(fd, TCSANOW, &options);
```

Comment: Have you tried using a `SIGIO` handler for your I2C device as well? Note that you can only have a single `SIGIO` handler per process.

Comment: Yeah I just tried and doesn't seem to work

Comment: `open("/dev/i2c-1", O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY | O_NDELAY);` I made this change in the above code. It is not working.

Comment: Did you try setting any flags on the opened device? What about the `O_ASYNC` flag?

Comment: No I didn't ... I edited the post to add what I did ..